# RestClient Behind Firewall

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client, cloudinary

Whenever the rails application tries to upload an image to cloudinary which is deployed in On-premise servers is throwing TimeOut errors.

I, [2016-12-21T14:55:24.617319 #923]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 60101ms (ActiveRecord: 49.7ms)
F, [2016-12-21T14:55:24.627524 #923] FATAL -- : 
RestClient::Exceptions::OpenTimeout (Timed out connecting to server):

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it the remote image that is protected by a firewall? If that is the case then you can contact Cloudinary to get a static IPs to whitelist on your on-premise servers (available from certain plan level).

Comment: once i configured the rest_client gem with the proxy url ,the cloudinary upload was working without issues.

Comment: So everything's good now?

Comment: yes..thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below option to set the proxy url for the rest_url which fixed the issue.

RestClient.proxy ="ProxyURL"

Comment: You should also be able to set proxies with the standard `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` environment variables.

Comment: The server was already configured with  http_proxy and https_proxy env variables but the rest client was not working until I configured the rest_client directly with proxy